# Intent Service completion

Tags: android, intentservice

I am downloading images via `Intent Service` in android. I would like to launch an activity on the completion of download of all the images. The images are well queued and the service works perfectly but I don't know when should I launch the activity which showcases those images in a `listview`  once they all are downloaded. Is there a functionality in place which tells me that the intent service has finished its task and that my downloads are done in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your service has to notify your activity that its work is done

Comment: Why do you need a mechanism to tell you when it's done? It's your service, you should tell when your code is done executing.

Comment: Normally you should use `AsyncTask` in your case, not a `IntentService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you send a request to `IntentService`, pass in an id in your `Intent`.Definitely you know what the last id is(it can be the last index in your list adapter, for instance).And in `onHandleIntent` when downloading completes check if the id in `Intent` is the last one. A value false indicates there're pending tasks.

Comment: Yes. I ended using a counter mechanism. I thought there should be an inbuilt oncompletion event. Thanks.